# Update na datatable depois de ter atualizado dados

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Fala galera, estou com um problema na atualização de uma coluna na minha datatable depois de uma edição. Uso um dialog para editar os dados desejados. Está tudo salvando no banco de dados, o problema é na hora de atualizar a tabela, os campos estão sendo atualizados com os valores novos, somente um que não está atualizando, justamente de um selectOneMenu que está no dialog. O campo que não está atualizando é da Lotação, os resto está tudo funfando.

Minha tabela..

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="TituloCorpo">Alterar Impressora</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="Corpo">

            <div align="center">
                <h:form id="form">

                    <!-- BOTÕES QUE GERA RELATÓRIOS EM PDF E CSV -->
                    <div style="width:2958px">

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon_pdf.png" width="35" title="Relatório em PDF"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tab" fileName="impressoras" pageOnly="true"/>
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon_csv.png" width="35" title="Relatório em CSV"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tab" fileName="impressoras" pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </div>

                    <!-- SCRIPT QUE CRIA UMA TABELA -->
                    <p:dataTable id="tab" var="impressora" widgetVar="tab" value="#{impressoraMB.impressoras}" editable="true" reflow="true" style="width:1100px">

                        <p:column id="fabricante" headerText="Fabricante" filterBy="#{impressora.fabricante}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:170px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.fabricante}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="modelo" headerText="Modelo" filterBy="#{impressora.modelo}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:170px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.modelo}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="modeloCartucho" headerText="Modelo do Cartucho" filterBy="#{impressora.modeloCartucho}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:180px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.modeloCartucho}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="patrimonio" headerText="Patrimonio" filterBy="#{impressora.patrimonio}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:120px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.patrimonio}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="lotacao" headerText="Lotação" filterBy="#{impressora.nome}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:110px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.nome}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Alterar" style="width:70px" exportable="false">
                            <p:commandButton update=":formAlterar:panelAlterar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Alterar" style="height:35px;width:35px"
                            oncomplete="PF('alterarImpre').show()" ajax="true">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{impressora}" target="#{impressoraMB.impressora}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Remover" style="width:90px" exportable="false">
                            <p:commandButton update=":formExcluir:panelExcluir" oncomplete="PF('excluirImpre').show()" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            styleClass="btn  btn-small" style="height:35px;width:35px" title="Excluir">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{impressora}" target="#{impressoraMB.impressora}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
```

Meu dialog..

```
<p:dialog id="editar" header="Altere os dados desejados" widgetVar="alterarImpre" width="600" location="center"
draggable="true" modal="true" responcive="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:form id="formAlterar">
        <h6 align="center"><i>*Para abrir o campo de edição, clique em cima do valor</i></h6>
        <br/>
        <h:panelGrid id="panelAlterar" columns="2" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
            <h:outputLabel for="fabricante" value="Fabricante:"/>
            <p:inplace id="fabricante" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.fabricante}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="modelo" value="Modelo:"/>
            <p:inplace id="modelo" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.modelo}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="modeloCartucho" value="Modelo do Cartucho: "/>
            <p:inplace id="modeloCartucho" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <h:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.modeloCartucho}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="patrimonio" value="Patrimonio"/>
            <p:inplace id="patrimonio" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.patrimonio}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="lotacoes" value="Lotações:"/>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="lotacoes" value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.id_Lotacoes}" effect="fold" required="true"
                immediate="true" style="width:100%">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{lotacoesMB.listLotacoes}" var="item"
                    itemLabel="#{item.nome}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
                    <f:ajax render=":form"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton id="btnAlterar" value="Alterar" action="#{impressoraMB.alterar}" onclick="PF('alterarImpre').hide()"
                    oncomplete="PF('tab').filter(); #{impressoraMB.impressora}" ajax="true" process="@this" title="Alterar">
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('alterarImpre').hide()" title="Cancelar"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Meu Bean..
    public class ImpressoraMB {

```
private Impressora impressora;
private ImpressoraDAO dao;
private List<Impressora> impressoras;

public ImpressoraMB() {
    impressora = new Impressora();
    impressoras = new ArrayList<Impressora>();
    dao = new ImpressoraDAO();
}

public List<Impressora> getImpressoras() {
    if (impressoras.size() == 0) {
        impressoras = dao.getImpressoras();
    }
    return impressoras;
}

public void adicionar() {
    dao.adicionar(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void remover() {
    dao.remover(impressora);
    impressoras.remove(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void alterar() {
    dao.alterar(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void showMsgAdicionar() {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Impressora adicionada", "com sucesso!");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
}

public Impressora getImpressora() {
    return impressora;
}
public void setImpressora(Impressora impressora) {
    this.impressora = impressora;
}
```

}

Deste já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido. o que estava de errado era porque na minha database estava usando impressora.nome e no meu dialog estava usando impressora.id_Lotacoes, então em um estava usando o id e no outro a descrição.

Answer (score 1):

Tente recarregar a pagina quando vc fizer seu update onchange="window.location.reload();" :

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="lotacoes"  ... onchange="window.location.reload();">
   <f:selectItems ... />
   <f:ajax ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta João Pedro, mas quando seleciono um valor ele já recarrega a página, então não altera os valores.